# Where does linux turn on virtual memory?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

Where in the linux source code does virtual memory get turned on? (e.g. in the intel processor, bit 31 of CR0 gets set to 1)

Comment: Can you tell where you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file arch/x86/boot/main.c in the linux source tree. It calls a function from arch/x86/boot/pm.c which does the specifics.

The grub bootloader can also set the processor to protected mode before passing control to the kernel, but linux itself doesn't depend on this.